# If there are no surrogate pairs in utf 8, why are they defined by char.GetUnicodeCategory

Tags: c#

```
string x = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(""));
foreach (var item in x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(char.GetUnicodeCategory(item));
}
```

Output:

Surrogate
Surrogate

Why is "Surrogate" output

Comment: tags in title: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190

Comment: Docs - _Surrogate code values are in the range U+D800 through U+DFFF_

Comment: the content of string/char isn't utf-8. Only your source was. And in the backing ucs-2 encoding used by .Net it can't be expressed as one char but as a surrogate pair.

Comment: Additionally `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` does nothing here when your sourcecode file is utf8 encoded. And if not presumably x would be something broken. As you would have interpreted the non utf8 character as utf8.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with Ralf in comments.

Your `x` is just a .NET `System.String` instance in memory. Such strings are always in UTF-16, and they may contain surrogate pairs.

Your string can also be written as:

```cs
string x = "\U0001f600";
```

or:

```cs
string x = char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x1f600);
```

It consists of one codepoint (rune), but it is in plane 1, so will need two *code units* (called two `char` by C#), so that is a surrogate pair.

If you inspect what is returned by `GetBytes`, though, you should see the values `f0 9f 98 80` (in hex). You see that is a single sequence for U+1f600. It is not one sequence for the high surrogate followed by another sequence for the low surrogate (that would be bad UTF-8).

Hope this helps.

Comment: FYI `are always in UTF-16` this isn't always the case anymore you can do UTF-8 strings in latest versions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/utf8-string-literals

Comment: @RandRandom The utf8 string literal is used to get a ReadOnlySpan<byte> not a string. I don't see having a utf8 string at runtime by this here.

Comment: @Ralf - thanks for the info, didn't use the feature myself only heard about it and the name `utf8 strings literal` made me believe you can declare a string literal

Comment: @RandRandom There is a Utf8String type mentioned for future implementation. So its at least on the horizon. Reading that part and all the occurrences of the word "regret" it feels like its rather not on the horizon :(

Comment: This does not have much relevance for the question asked, but for the sake of a hypothetical future .NET type `System.Utf8String` that could be introduced, I changed "string" to "`System.String`" in my answer.